# The integral of $\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz$ over the semicircle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

If $\gamma$ is the part of the circle of radius $R$ in the upper half plane of $\mathbb{C}$, I would like to calculate
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz.$$
Can anybody help me?

I tried to used the parameter representation $R e^{i t}$, but then I got
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{R e^{i t}}{R^2 e^{i 2 t}+1}d t,$$
which is not very useful either.

Comment: Let $C$ be the closed contour consisting of the interval $[-R,R]$ on the real line and $\gamma$. Can you evaluate $$\int_C \frac{1}{z^2+1}\,dz$$ and $\int_{-R}^R \frac{dx}{x^2+1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $z=Re^{it}$ for $t\in [0,\pi]$ (with $R>0$ and $R\not=1$) and note that $(\arctan z)'=1/(1+z^2)$.
Hence
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=\int_0^\pi\frac{iR e^{i t}}{R^2 e^{i 2 t}+1}d t=[\arctan(Re^{it})]_0^{\pi}=?$$

P.S. As pointed out by Daniel Fischer, be careful 
to choose the right branch of the [complex function $\arctan(z)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html) whether $0<R<1$ or $R>1$. What follows explains the difference between the two cases in an alternative way (we use the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem)).

If $0<R<1$ then the closed path $\gamma\cup [-R,R]$ does not contain any pole and 
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=-\int_{-R}^R\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=-2\arctan(R).$$
If $R>1$ then the closed path $\gamma\cup [-R,R]$ contains the pole $i$, and
$$\int_\gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}dz=-\int_{-R}^R\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx
+2\pi i \mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^2+1},i\right)=-2\arctan(R)+\pi.$$
In both cases $\arctan$ denotes the usual real function.

Comment: Yes I knew that, thank you! But my numerator is not $1$, I have something like $\frac{x}{x^2+1}$. Are you sure I can use this derivative of the arctan?

Comment: @Carucel What is the derivative of $\arctan(Re^{it})$ with respect to $t$?

Comment: Aha thank you! I understand: you use integration by substitution.

Comment: @Carucel Yes, that is the way.

Comment: @Carucel If $R > 1$, you must be careful to choose the right branch of $\arctan$ to evaluate the integral.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I see, so the correct branch is along the real axis? Could you fill in the final result for me?

Comment: @Carucel For $R > 1$, you need a branch that is defined on a neighbourhood of the semicircle. Choosing a branch defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{ ti : t \in [-1,1]\}$ is then the simplest.

Comment: @RobertZ I don't understand the relevance of what you did for $\;R>1\;$ as then you give the value of the integral **in that closed path**, which is *not* what was asked...and even then the value of the integral **on the asked path** (i.e., the upper semicircle of radius $\;R\;$) remains the same and you just add $\;2\pi i\;$ times the function's residue at $\;i\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I think that for $R>1$ the integral on the asked path is $-2\arctan(R)+\pi$. Do you agree? Reading your answer it seems that the result is always $-2\arctan(R)$  (where $\arctan$ denotes the usual real function). Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Use your idea:

$$z=Re^{it}\;,\;\;0\le t\le \pi\implies dz=Rie^{it}\implies$$

$$\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{1+z^2}=\int_0^\pi\frac{Rie^{it}}{1+R^2e^{2it}}=\left.\int_0^\pi\frac{d(Re^{it})}{1+(Re^{it})^2}=\arctan Re^{it}\right|_0^\pi=$$

$$=\arctan(-R)-\arctan R=-2\arctan R$$

You may want this for some real integral by means of complex integration: you can see now that

$$\lim_{r\to\infty}-2\arctan R=-\pi$$

Comment: You picked a wrong branch of $\arctan$ for $R > 1$. The limit of the integral as $R \to +\infty$ is $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer In this case I think "wrong" is in the beholder's eyes as the given path doesn't pass through neither of the well known branches points $\;\pm i\;$ of the arctangent if $\;R>1\;$ , say, nor the the integration is on a closed curve. Now, as it stands, I don't think this matters **unless**, of course, the problem is embedded in some frame. You also comment in the other answer to choose "the correct" branch: what is **the** correct branch *in this* case? Can it be decided without any further info? I am not sure, as with log or square root there is no *correct branch*, imo.

Comment: You need a branch that is defined on the whole path. Which of those branches you choose doesn't matter. But for $R > 1$, such a branch does not give the result $-2\arctan R$. The integral $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$ is, for $R\neq 1$, a well-defined complex number, and if your evaluation of the integral using $\arctan$ yields a wrong result, you chose a wrong branch.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I can see your point, yet the basic question remains: how do you know *a priori* that the evaluation of the integral using whatever is a wrong result? This looks like a vicious circle...

Comment: By the standard estimate, we know that for $R > 1$ we have $$\biggl\lvert \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2+1}\biggr\rvert \leqslant \frac{\pi R}{R^2-1},$$ so if we have something that doesn't tend to $0$ as $R\to +\infty$, we know that that must be wrong. And we can close the contour using the interval $[-R,R]$ on the real line, use whichever version of the residue theorem we like most to evaluate the integral over the closed contour, and then subtract the part we added, which we know how to compute with real methods.